# Finding the last association created today

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model, the `User` model has a `UserLogins` association, `UserLogins` is created after every login to track information about the session.

I need to find all `Users` who's last `UserLogin` was created today. I've been trying various solutions all night and can't wrap my head around it, joins/group is a pain!

Any guideance would be awesome.

Comment: You can try this - `User.joins(:user_logins).where(user_logins: {"created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day}`

Comment: This will find all user_logins created today though, I only want to find users whos LAST login was today, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:user_logins).where('user_logins.created_at > ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day).group('users.id')
```

This should give you unique list. Only problem with this query is that running .count will give you hash result and not a number.

Comment: What if I had to do it for the last login 3 days ago, how would I build this in?

Comment: Change where clause, `where('user_logins.created_at > ? AND user_logins.created_at < ?', start_time, end_time)`

Just put appropiate times instead of start and end time. You can use beginning_of_day and end_of_day methods on Time objects.